# Inline style precedence over sheet and style tag?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to override the style sheet for my wordpress site and remove the underline from specific Anchors.

e.g.

```
<a href="https://www.mypagehere/" data-emacategory="In-Page Navigation">My Page Title Here</a>
```

here is the CSS

```
a, a:active, a:hover, a:visited {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}


a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: auto;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I tried the adding inline style "text-decoration: none" to the anchor tag but it does not seem to work.

```
<a href="https://www.mypagehere/" data-emacategory="In-Page Navigation" style="text-decoration: none">My Page Title Here</a>
```

what am i doing wrong? I thought inline style has precedence over style sheet and style tag?

Comment: why do you use a:-webkit-any-link??

Comment: Inline style works.. check here https://jsfiddle.net/gk0623zy/

Comment: try to add !important-> text-decoration: none !important;

Comment: Inline style is not working for me.

Comment: @buxbeatz - tried it and still no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you add `!important` to the `css` like this:

```
<a href="https://www.mypagehere/" data-emacategory="In-Page Navigation" style="text-decoration:none!important">My Page Title Here</a>
```

Comment: that does not change anything.